# Find GTK version using Terminal

Tags: 16.04, unity, gtk, versions

How can I find my current GTK version using Terminal ? Is there a command for that ? I use 16.04 + Unity.

Comment: Try `dpkg -l | grep libgtk`. There may be more then one "my current GTK version".

Comment: I see. I was trying to make a bug report and it asked for GTK version. What to do now ? Thanks.

Comment: Well, now you can "make a bug report". Welcome.

Comment: @mikewhatever I don't know which value to share. There were like 10 of them.

Comment: You may have two version of GTK, one on the v3 branch (libgtk-3-0 package), the other one on v2 (libgtk2.0-0 package). A software can be build to use the v2 or v3. If you are unsure, provide both version in your bug report.

Answer (score 1):

`apt-cache policy libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0` (optionally pipe to grep Installed)

or

```
dpkg -l libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0
```